# How to unsign bcprov-jdk15on-146.jar in windows 7?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, jar

According to the tutorial [Extending the Mobile Backend](https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/extend_backend), I need to unsign the bcprov-jdk15on-146.jar,

> Download the bcprov-jdk15on-146.jar file. By default, the downloaded jar file is signed. Execute the following command to unsign this jar file zip -d bcprov-jdk15on-146.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF.

but I don't know how to unsign this jar in windows 7. Where is the command "zip"?.

Is there some site where I can download the unsigned bcprov-jdk15on-146.jar?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found my own solution, just open the .jar with a program like "WinRar", and delete the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file.